# Storing WCF rest request data with SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: .net, sql-server, sqlclr

I have a simple interface in my WCF service with one method which gets a `myRequest` parameter

```
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string MyOperation(myRequest request);
}
```

When I'm posting the data from the client, the content type is `application/json`, so the request body auto deserialise into `myRequest` object.

`myRequest` is a WCF `DataContract`:

```
[DataContract]
public class myRequest
{
    string id;
    string name;
    List<Phone> phones

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string ID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<Phone> Phones { get; set; }
}
```

and the `Phone` class

```
public class Phone
{
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "[" + Number + "," + Type + "]";
    }
}
```

Ok, so now I would like to store the request data into my local SQL Server database and for that I need to use stored procedures. I want to send the `myRequest` object to SQL Server and let it deal with insert/update (I think what I will have to keep 2 tables: people and phones).

I don't have to much background about stored procedures but I will great to get from you guys the right approach to solve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way you can pass a complex object to the db, and it does not matter if you use a CLR stored proc, an *old plain stored proc* or something else.

You'll need to transform your request into something that can be passed to the db. An XML serialisation is a good candidate for the job, if you know how to manipulate XML in T-Sql (which could be a little tricky).

I think abandoning the idea of using stored procedures and embracing something else (like EF) would be better for you.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I found this tutorial http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/739164/Entity-Framework-Tutorial-for-Beginners It seems like I can use EF with stored procedures (for more complex inserts to multiple tables).

Comment: Yes, EF support stored procedures. But with just 2 tables involved (and - furthermore - with such a simple tables) I will not go with it. May be there are other specific reasons you did not mention?

Comment: Not really, I think EF will do the job.. but there's another issue.. When I'm trying use the EF within the service (store the contact into the database).. the client gets 400 bad request.. There's a chance that I have to  deploy the service to the IIS? If indeed it's gonna be a problem because I don't want that the client will be depend on IIS server

Comment: I think this is material for another SO question

Comment: Just did ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30153308/entity-framework-through-wcf-service-without-iis