# Entity Framework through WCF service (without IIS)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf

Regarding this thread I've opened earlier:

[Storing WCF rest request data with SQL Server stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30128039/storing-wcf-rest-request-data-with-sql-server-stored-procedure/30129587#30129587)

I have a simple interface in my `WCF` service with one method which gets a `myRequest` parameter

```
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string MyOperation(myRequest request);
}
```

When I'm posting the data from the client, the content type is `application/json`, so the request body auto deserialise into `myRequest` object.

`myRequest` is a `WCF` `DataContract`:

```
[DataContract]
public class myRequest

{
    string id;
    string Name;

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Id { get; set; }

}

public string MyOperation(myRequest request)
{
    if (request != null) {
        Contact contact = new Contact();
        contact.Id = Int32.Parse(request.Id);
        contact.DisplayName = request.Name;

        ContentContext db = new ContentContext();
        db.Contacts.Add(contact);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return "ok";
    }

    SetResponseHttpStatus(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
    return null;
}
```

And finaly, hosting the service:

```
public class ProgramBL {
    public static void StartServer()
        {

            ServiceHost streamer = new ServiceHost(typeof(DataStreaming.StreamService));


            streamer.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Service up and running at:");
            foreach (var ea in streamer.Description.Endpoints)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ea.Address);
            }

            Program._StreamerHost = streamer;
        }
}
```

`_StreamerHost` its a static member of the `Program` class.

When I try to use the EF through `WCF rest` service hosted by Console/Application.
When I'm trying to do it - the client gets always `400 Bad Request` response.

Another thing - I created a new project in the solution for the database model, the `WCF` service is another project, so I added refrence of the database model project to the service project. To achive this I had to install and add a refrence to the Nuget Entityframe work package.

Any solutions?

Thanks

Comment: Post your code please.  This will help us help you

Comment: Please enter the link I added, It's a SO thread I have opened few hours ago, the conclusion made me open this new thread...

Comment: Hmm.  No console client code there nor here though

Comment: SetResponseHttpStatus(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
return null; who is returning null?

Comment: It happens only if request == null. It was a copy/paste issue. I have fixed it.. MyOperation method does not firing and when I googled about it I found the issue is about deploying the service to IIS

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I solved the problem.

I have installed the `NuGet` Entity framework library only at the service project (I used the built in library at the database project).
After I have installed the `NuGet` Entity framework on the database project + added the `connectionString` to the service `App.config` everything seems to be OK.